# how to add normalize.css in index.scss file with react app

Tags: reactjs, sass, normalize

Currently, I'm working with scss and create-react-app. I'm having problems including normalize to the main file index.scss.

Should like something like: index.css;

> @import-normalize; /* bring in normalize.css styles */
>
> /* rest of app styles */

The **@import-normalize;** doesn't work with scss.

any advice? thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@import-normalize;` is not something which is exclusively defined in scss.

You can stick to basic by including the css file in scss by using @import.

```
@import "../pathTo/normalise.css";
```

A better way would be to rename `normalise.css` to `_normalise.scss` and include it simply by:

```
@import "../pathTo/normalise";
```

**PS: the scss files that start with `_` are called partials, and do not create a separate "normalise.css" when all of the scss files are compiled.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `sass` and `create-react-app` this should work out of the box in a .sass file: `@import "~normalize.css/normalize.css";`